# AsyncTask doInbackground returns arraylist value but in onPostExecute arraylist is 0

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-asynctask

In Asynctask **doInBackground** I get arraylist from firebase database and return arraylist(return 30 maps) result but in **onPostExecute** arraylist is 0 (doesn't keep data that was in doInbackground). I think problem in - **doInBackground** work like a parallel thread. Ok. 
   I also tried to insert data which is in **doInbackground** to onCreate but it's not working also(return arraylist 0). 
  That's my code. What is the wrong with my code?

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
        parseTitle.execute();
    }
public class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        avLoadingIndicatorView = (com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.avi);
        avLoadingIndicatorView.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref1 = database.getReference("work");
        ref = ref1.child("worker");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String s_position = (String) ds.child("v_position").getValue();
                    String s_employer = (String) ds.child("v_company").getValue();
                    String s_posted = (String) ds.child("v_post").getValue();
                    String s_link = (String) ds.child("v_url").getValue();

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("POSITION", s_position);
                    map.put("EMPLOYER", s_employer);
                    map.put("POSTED", s_posted);
                    map.put("LINK", s_link);
                    map.put("TYPE", "IT");
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
               // System.out.println("The read failed: " + DatabaseError.DATA_STALE);
            }
        });
        return  arraylist;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
      //  Collections.sort(arraylist,SortByValue);
        //HashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = (HashMap<String, Integer>) sortByValue(arraylist);
       // if(arraylist != null && arraylist.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(IT.this, arraylist);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            avLoadingIndicatorView.hide();
            findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      //  }
    }
}
```

It will be very good if somebody help me with trouble appointed above. :)

Comment: Where are you declaring `arraylist`?  In any case, `onPostExecute` will only be called by Android _after_ the async task has completed, and this is guaranteed.  So your concern that it hasn't finished yet can't be true AFAIK.

Comment: sorry buddy, initialise your arraylist in onPreExcute and check...

Comment: @SuryanarayanaReddy how to do that? Can you show?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Arraylist is declaring in doInBackground.

Comment: No it's not.  You _initialize_ it in the background task, but you certainly don't declare it there.  Where do you declare it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I declared it in  main activity - **public class IT extends Activity** {     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

Comment: @NeoFar Try the answer below, if that would fix it, but it shouldn't be necessary from what I can see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `AsyncTask` is not needed because the `FirebaseDatabase` events are called asynchronous. Your `doInBackground` just runs through really quick and `onPostExecute` is called before you receive the result in `onDataChange`.
Without the `AsyncTask` it could look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
        parseTitle.execute();
avLoadingIndicatorView = (com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.avi);
avLoadingIndicatorView.show();
arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref1 = database.getReference("vacancies");
ref = ref1.child("jobsearch");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String s_position = (String) ds.child("v_position").getValue();
            String s_employer = (String) ds.child("v_company").getValue();
            String s_posted = (String) ds.child("v_post").getValue();
            String s_link = (String) ds.child("v_url").getValue();

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("POSITION", s_position);
            map.put("EMPLOYER", s_employer);
            map.put("POSTED", s_posted);
            map.put("LINK", s_link);
            map.put("TYPE", "IT");
            arraylist.add(map);
        }
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(IT.this, arraylist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        avLoadingIndicatorView.hide();
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I checked like you adviced me and that's working. But there 1-2 sec waiting.ok that's not so ugly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(IT.this, arraylist);
```

with

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(IT.this, result);
```

Comment: İ just check as you wrote but result size is also 0.

Comment: This may not be necessary, assuming `arrayList` is defined in a scope which would also be visible to `onPostExecute`.

Comment: need initialize arrayList in constructor, outside doInBackground();

Comment: I deleted arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); from doInbackground but now arraylist returns null. That's not work...

Comment: create constructor for the class ParseTitle. init arryList there

Comment: Thank you @Yossi I'll check later with constructor.For now I made how Björn Kechel adviced me.